# Assume that the Twin prime conjecture is true, prove that there are infinitely many pairs of positive integers m and n such that $\phi(m)=\sigma(n)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

From a comment, I have corrected my proof. Here's what I have now.

The Twin Prime Conjecture sates: There are infinitely many prime numbers $p$ for which $p+2$ is also a prime number.We consider 61 and 59, they are twin primes. $\phi(61)=60$ and $\sigma(59)=60$. So because $\phi(p)=p-1$ where p is prime and $\sigma(p)=p+1$ we can take that $m$ and $n$ are twin prime so $m=n+2$. So $m=n+2$ is equal to $m-1=n+1$ which is the same as $\phi(m)=\sigma(n)$, therefore $\phi(m)=\sigma(n)$ is ture for all twin prime integers. Hence if there are infinitely many twin primes then there are infinitely pairs of positive integers such that $\phi(m)=\sigma(n)$.

Comment: Take $59$ and $61$ for example. What is $\varphi(61)$? What is $\sigma(59)$? Can you generalize?

Comment: $\phi(61)=60$ and $\sigma(59)=60$. So because $\phi(p)=p-1$ where p is prime and $\sigma(p)=p+1$. m and n is prime and m=n+2. So $\phi(m)=\sigma(n)$ = $m-1=n+1$ so m=n+2. Therefore if there are infinitely many twin primes then there are infinitely pairs of positive integers such that $\phi(m)=\sigma(n)$. Hows this for a rough draft?

Comment: @JackHilton-Jones This looks correct. If you want, you can add it as an answer to your question; then the question can be marked as answered. (See [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) for some information on self-answering if you're interested.)

Comment: Thank you both for your help